# What is the discriminant of $t^4 - 2(p+q)t^3 +(p-q)t -1$?

Tags: polynomials

How is it possible to find that the discriminant of $$t^4 - 2(p+q) t^3 + 2(p-q)t -1$$ is equal to $\Delta = 27p^2q^2 - (q^2 - p^2 -1)^3$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $$\Delta=\prod_{i\ne j}(x_i-x_j), $$
where $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ are the roots of the polynomial.
We are given that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=2(p+q)$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4=0$, $x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4=2^?(q-p)$ and $x_1x_2x_3x_4=1$.
Laboriously expanding everything will show that equality holds.

Comment: So there are no tricky-but-simple manipulations to obtain the discriminant ?